# Trouble Setting up Multipage RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I am trying to use RequireJS in a multi-page project as per the instructions here: https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage

I have a page main.html...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/components/require/require.js"></script>
    <script>
        require([ "/common.js" ], function ( common ) {
            require([ "/app/views/main.js" ]);
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body />
</html>
```

And I have a module main.js...

```
define(function( require ) {

    var $ = require( "jquery" );
    var _ = require( "underscore" );
    var Backbone = require( "backbone" );

    $(function() {
        var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function() {
                alert( "hah!" );
            }
        });
        new MainView();
    });
});
```

This codes executes fine.  So far so good.  The trouble I am running into, is when I try to require another sub-view from within the main view.

So if I change main.js...

```
define(function( require ) {

    var $ = require( "jquery" );
    var _ = require( "underscore" );
    var Backbone = require( "backbone" );
    var SubView = require( "/app/views/subview" );

    $(function() {
        var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function() {
                this.subView = new SubView();
            }
        });
        new MainView();
    });
});
```

And if I add a subview.js...

```
define(function( require ) {

    var $ = require( "jquery" );
    var _ = require( "underscore" );
    var Backbone = require( "backbone" );

    $(function() {
        var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function() {
                alert( "SubView Hah!" );
            }
        });
        return SubView;
    });
});
```

Suddenly requirejs returns an error:  "require.js:8 Error: Script error for: views/subview.js"

According to the Require JS documentation this error is typically triggered by syntax error / typo (http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror).  However I do not think that is the problem in my case.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently in your `main.js` `SubView` is `undefined`, that is because your subview is not returning anything.

### SubView

```
define(function(require)
{
    // These 2 require calls are not needed since they are not "required" for this module.
    //var $ = require( "jquery" );
    //var _ = require( "underscore" );
    var Backbone = require("backbone");

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function()
        {
            alert( "SubView Hah!" );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I do actually return the SubView, I just do it at the bottom.  I tried your syntax but got the same error.

Comment: @user2796982 Your returning subview inside `$(function(){});` not your definition function. Which you also do in `main.js` look [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#deffunc)